# clojure: how to use recur in if statement

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

Disclaimer: I'm learning clojure.

This is the simple example I'm trying to run:

```
(ns ClojureTest.core)

(let [input (read-line)]
  ;if user input = "x"
  (if (= "x" input)
    ;stop accepting input
    (println "Exit")
    ;else output the input and continue accepting input
    (
      (println input)
      (recur)
    )
  )
)
```

Now I'm getting this error, which I guess makes sense, because I'm unfamiliar with syntax:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position, compiling:(ClojureTest/core.clj:8:7)
```

How do I fix this?

Side questions:

1. When I click "run" in eclipse (as I would do with Java) I get not only the console opened but this "REPL" window. Why is it necessary and what does it do?
2. When I click "run" it takes quite a few seconds to launch the app. Is there a way to make it faster?
3. When I need to edit the code and relaunch the app I'm getting this message: "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches". What is that and why wouldn't it let me relaunch my code? If I wait a while I can launch it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you're missing a `do` in the "else" clause of the `if`:

```
(do
  (println input)
  (recur))
```

Without the `do`, you've got `((println input) (recur))`, which looks like a function call with the return value of `(println input)` being the function to call and `(recur)` being the argument expression and so, not in tail position.

(Clearly `(println input)` would return `nil` and attempting to call that as a function would throw a `NullPointerException`, but this is irrelevant here -- it would be a runtime error, whereas the `recur`-not-in-tail-position problem is detectable at compile time.)